# Managing multiple AJAX calls to PHP scripts

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a set of 5 HTML dropdowns that act as filters for narrowing results returned from a mySQL database. The three pertinent filters are for "Province", "Region", and "City" selection, respectively.

I have three functions:

1. `findSchools()`, which runs when any of the filters (marked with CSS class `.filter`) are changed, and fetches the results via AJAX from a PHP script. Once that is done, two other functions are called...
2. `changeRegionOptions()`, which, upon changing the "Province" filter, and updates the available options using the same method as the first function, but posting to a different script.
3. `changeCityOptions()`, which runs if the "Region" filter was changed, and updates options, again using the same method.

The problem is that since I want these AJAX functions to run simultaneously, and they by nature run asynchronously, I've tried using `$.when` to control the execution of the functions, but it doesn't fix the problem.

The functions run, but the Region and City filters return blank (no options); the FireBug report shows absolutely no output, even though the POST request went through. The posted parameter for filter_province gets sent normally, but the one for region gets cut off at the end -- it sends as `filter_region=`, with no value passed. So I'm presuming my logic is wrong somewhere. The code is below:

```
// When any of the filters are changed, let's query the database...
$("select.filter").change(function() {
    findSchools();
});

  // First, we see if there are any results...
      function findSchools() {

          var sch_province = document.filterform.filter_province.value;
          var sch_region = document.filterform.filter_region.value;
          var sch_city = document.filterform.filter_city.value;
          var sch_cat = document.filterform.filter_category.value;
          var sch_type = document.filterform.filter_type.value;

          $.post("fetch_results.php",
          { filter_province : sch_province,
            filter_region : sch_region,
            filter_city : sch_city,
            filter_category : sch_cat,
            filter_type : sch_type },

            function(data) {

              $("#results").html("");
              $("#results").hide();
              $("#results").html(data);
              $("#results").fadeIn(600);
            }
          );

    // Once the results are fetched, we want to see if the filter they changed
       was the one for Province, and if so, update the Region and City options
        to match that selection...

            $("#filter_province").change(function() {

                $.when(findSchools())
                .done(changeRegionOptions());

                $.when(changeRegionOptions())
                .done(changeCityOptions());
        });
  };
```

This is just one of the ways I've tried to solve it; I've tried using an IF statement, and tried calling the functions directly inside the general `select.filter.change()` function (after `findSchools();` ), but they all return the same result.

Any help with this would be great!

Comment: I've read this several times and can't understand why the need for changes to all selects every time one is changed. Logic seems flawed. Create a simplified demo in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I've created a slightly modified jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xNvVF/11/

Comment: If by changing all the selects with only one changed, you mean the `(select.filter).change()` triggered function, this is used to query and return results from a database, nothing else.

The page it is used on is a search results page, and the filters are used to narrow search results. It takes the values of all selects and sends them to the PHP script, which then uses those values to build and execute the mySQL query for returning a list of schools matching those criteria. It is then sent back to the same page and "instantly" updated (no need to reload the page).

Comment: Perosnally I think you should simply start over. Do a google search for `jquery cascading select` or `jquery mulitiple select`. Your logic is still flawed and there are tutorials and plugins that will make this a lot easier for you. Do you really need a list of every school in a province when only province is selected?? If so, why go back to server and not store the data locally once you have it?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I rewrote most of it and it seems to be working okay now (set `async` to `false` and ditched the changing of all dropdowns on one click). The problem was that I was experiencing a race condition with the three AJAX requests: before the region dropdown options could be changed to match the province, it would send a region value that did not match the province, which would produce weird results like `filter_province=1`, but `filter_region=16` (not matching); that would of course throw my 'Results not found' error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn async to false. After that, your code will be executed line by line.

For example like this, before calling $.post

```
$.ajaxSetup({async:false});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .hope this is what you were expecting. [jsfiddle->sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/xNvVF/12/)